# Prevent upgrade to 4.3 on rooted 4.2.2. device

Tags: updates, root-access

I have just rooted a Nexus 7 with Android 4.2.2. I now receive a notification for system upgrade to 4.3. I don't want to do this, probably ever, as I want to keep 4.2 for app testing purposes. In *Settings > About tablet > System updates*
and in there it says:
**Android System 4.3 Update

[Restart & Install]**

How do I prevent the upgrade, ie how to I get rid of that Restart & Install button and to I prevent future upgrades & notifications?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but Google provides system images for testing purposes so that you can restore to any supported Android version for your Nexus device: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images

Comment: @wawa The system images will try to upgrade again.

Answer (score 2):

Go to this XDA-Developers thread and follow the instructions. You have to download an APK from there and install it as a system app.

[[How-to] Disable OTA updates on Stock + Rooted ROMs - xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2249350)

Comment: Worked for me when trying to keep my Nexus 7 on 4.2.1